# Disable predictive text in Webview

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview displaying a website. I want to prevent the keyboard to predict words when the user is typing.

For example, when I write "100", I don't want any of what is in the red part.
[image: Android keyboard with predictive]

Very simple purpose, but can't find a solution.

I've no access to the website code, so I want to do this in my android app, maybe in the manifest I suppose.

I tried the following, that didn't work :

```
this.mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
this.mWebView.clearFormData();
```

If someone could help, it would be very very useful !
Thanks

Comment: For when webview already has the data: `WebView.getInstance(this).clearFormData();`

Comment: Not completely sure, but I think that what you're seeing there is not related to the `WebView`, but to the keyboard itself. Maybe using Layout Inspector in Android Studio will give you some hints, to try to figure out if the highlighted part is created by the keyboard or by the `WebView`. If it's keyboard's, then I think there's little you can do.

Comment: For me, it's part of the keyboard. So I'm hoping that some option exist to customize the way that the keyboard  is displayed, something to add in the project configuration for example... or when the activity starts